# What is "to:" keyword in python's def parenthesis?

Tags: python, function

While I am reading the book "Using Asyncio in Python 3" I encountered a line of def definition such as below. There is "to:" keyword inside the def parenthesis and it seems like ":" here is different with "=" but I couldn't figure out what ":" is and for what purpose.

What is "to:" in below code?

```py
@attrs
class Cutlery:
    knives = attrib(default=0)
    forks = attrib(default=0)

    def give(self, to: 'Cutlery', knives=0, forks=0):
        self.change(-knives, -forks)
        to.change(knives, forks)

    def change(self, knives, forks):
        self.knives += knives
        self.forks += forks
```

Comment: This means, that the argument `to` should be of the type `Cutlery`. Its a type annotation.

Answer (score 0):

`to` is a regular function parameter, and the colon indicates a [type hint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) (also called annotation). This means that `to` is expected to be of type `Cutlery`. These annotations are not checked by default, but you can do so by running third-party checkers like [`mypy`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) on your code.